# What do you do about high cider FG?

Tags: cider, final-gravity, kits, fruit-extract

I went ahead and tried one of Mangrove Jack's cider kits — the raspberry and mango one if anyone is interested. Shoved the fermentation bucket into the garage, and checked in after a couple of weeks. I noticed quite a bit of the infamous *rhino farts*, which was unpleasant, and the SG was around 1.011. Realising that the temperatures were probably a bit low (nothing too extreme, around 17–18 degrees Celsius) for the yeast at this point, I moved it inside and left it for another week. Now, according the Mangrove Jack's website, FG should be 1.006 ± 0.002 for this cider, but it seems to have stalled at ~1.009, might be 1.010 (I find it's sometimes hard to read on the bloody hydrometer :P ), which feels somewhat high to me. I used dextrose together with the extracts, so I would have expected it to finish lower.

So, what do you guys think? Is it possible I'm getting low attenuation because of low initial temperatures (the sachet said 20–25 degrees Celcius, whoops!)? Maybe it's just varying degree of frementables in the syrup from Mangrove Jack's? Would you wait longer? Would you try repitching? Any input would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably let it sit another week. The FG only seems one point of from their range. Your temperature would have slowed fermentation but should not have killed it to be honest.

I wouldnt bother repitching yeast unless you intend to use a yeast with a much higher attenuation (eg champagne yeast) but that will also effectively dry out your yeast.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Yes, I was thinking that the single point off might be within the margin of error. I just don't want to make bottle bombs, and, for some reason, I seem to consistently get higher than expected FGs in my brews. Maybe it's the yeast; maybe it's the extracts.

Comment: I agree with this. I think all you need to do is to be more patient. Give it two more weeks to be on the safe side. By then it’s probably going to be done fermenting and should lose another two or three points of specific gravity.  If you bottled right now, you might indeed get bottle bombs.

Comment: @dmtaylor Ok, I suppose patience is a virtue. I think I get impatient because of kits claiming to be "DONE IN 6 DAYS! SUPER FAST AND EASY!" And then, in reality, you have to wait a lot longer. :P